# New Website Project Silverlight / Php

Tags: php, silverlight

Very recently I have been given a facebook like project to develop for a client of mine.

Most of the time when i comes to web development I use php since the solution PHP, apache, MySql which are all freely availble solutions, I have been thinking about using Silverlight to develop the web application, and I would like to hear some pros and cons with develping a web application in silverlight. 
what do you use to host the application? its costs and so on compared a LAMP solution.

Thanks,
  Eric.

Answer (score 4):

Having not a clue of the type of app you're building, I need to ask: why do you think you need Silverlight? The main problem with walled-garden solutions like Flash and Silverlight is that they do not play very well with the users model of their browser. Things like bookmarks and back button tend to do the wrong thing. You can't easily navigate away and come back to what you were doing. Jeff and Joel have ranted about this in their podcasts.

Nearly everything you can imagine needing Silverlight / Flash for these days can probably be handled by a javascript/jQuery UI kit / plugin of some sort ..

Silverlight especially still has a pretty low penetration rate even with MS holding it up for you to accept during updates.

I do think there are types of applications for which these technologies make sense. Especially if they are very heavily graphically or interactively intensive. I would look at Flex sooner than Silverlight in that case.

Comment: the application is a community site like facebook on a smaller scale, i was thinking of silverlight because i recently started using WPF for some client developments and i feel that the XAML markup is very good and and helps development speeds. could you please elaborate on the enviorment needed?

Comment: since you have listed PHP in your tags, i guess i'd say take a look at Drupal first. It's very rich and evolved and has "millions" of plugins that will get you whereever you wanna go very fast...

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the decision starts off with who needs to access this application. If it's got to run on a wide range of browsers and platforms, you're safer sticking with HTML, CSS & JavaScript as the technologies. If you're happy with PHP as the server side technology, then stick with it. You'll find the learning curve for .NET applications pretty steep.

That said, for larger projects, the slightly better practises that .NET tends to push you towards helps. Some PHP projects start small and then need to scale exposing flaws in the original architecture. The same thing obviously can happen with .NET but less so IMHO as the programmers using it tend to have slightly more disiplined training. There are of course, exceptions to all rules.

The attraction of Silverlight though is big - the ability to develop client side code in familar .NET languages and not JavaScript is appealing. Personally, the whole HTML, CSS and JavaScript (with Ajax) set-up is offensive from an asthetic point of view :-)

Rob.

PS. It will be more expensive for the development environment and back-end compared to LAMP. Only you can decide whether the investment is worthwhile.

Comment: Rob, since im not so familiar with MS technoliges what options do i have for web site development besides ASP and Silverlight? i do have some expirence with WPF and i would like to put that to use if possible. also is it possible to run the sliverlight application on a UNIX machine with apache?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a website in SilverLight is as bad of an idea as using Flash:

- Users cant print
- Users can't bookmark
- Search engines can't index specific
  "pages"

Silverlight exists for the reason of making apps that aren't possible with traditional HTML/JS and a Facebook like app is not one of them.

Comment: Is there any MS technology that is suitible for creating a website (hopfully one that i could run on an UNIX machine with apache) that isnt ASP? I really like the XAML markup and if i can use C# as the server side language that would be awsome.

Comment: There are work arounds to not being able to print and bookmark. Some half creative programming can fix that :)

Answer (score 0):

If facebook itself uses PHP, why not develop it in PHP?